# Could transfusion of a different blood type cure blood-based cancers?

Tags: cancer, hematology, autoimmune, antigen, transfusion

Different antigen detection triggers an immune system response that could perhaps stimulate mitochondria and such in killing cancer cells - something like chemo without the hair-loss?

Comment: It is the other way round. For example, post bone marrow transplant reinfusion of donor lymphocytes (termed DLI) is used as a means of triggering a graft-versus-host reaction to prevent relapse in hematogenous cancers.

Comment: @Raoul It has a special name: [graft-versus-tumor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graft_versus_tumor_effect) in this case.

Comment: @inf3rno yes. Btw I hold an M.D on the complications of DLI ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[No](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK2265/). When a different blood type is introduced in the body, the host immune system recognizes the foreign blood as non-self and attacks it. The transfused blood becomes useless, and the potentially massive immune reaction can cause shock, which itself can be fatal.

More details in the book [Blood Groups and Red Cell Antigens](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK2261/), which can be found at the NCBI library.